# How to prevent nlog from using config file?

Tags: c#, nlog

NLog's behavior can be configured [both via configuration files and programmatically](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10631/Introduction-to-NLog).

It seems like when I set up programmatic rules, any configuration file present is still processed, so both mechanisms are in play at the same time.  Is this accurate?

Is it possible to set up NLog to use only programmatic rules and prevent it from reading any config files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
LogManager.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration(); // Assigns configuration from code
Logger Log = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger(); // Only loads configuration from xml file, when no configuration assigned
```

if you use one of these methods, respectively, and it will work

more info: https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki

Answer (score 3):

To expand on Sergey's answer, suppose you have a LogFactory:

```
var factory = new LogFactory()
```

When access `factory.Configuration`-property or `factory.GetLogger(...)`, then it tries to read configuration data from a configuration file.  You can adjust, or supplement, this configuration

```
factory.Configuration.LoggingRules.Add( ... )
```

However you can also just *replace* the configuration with your own:

```
factory.Configuration = new LoggingConfiguration();
```

In this case, any configuration that got loaded is discarded and now you are proceeding with just the rules that you create in code.

Answer (score 0):

If no configuration has already been assigned, then NLog will attempt to [automatically load](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-file#configuration-file-locations) `NLog.config`, when calling `LogManager.GetLogger` / `LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger`.

NLog v5 introduces the [fluent configuration API](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API), to make it easy to setup the NLog configuration and skip loading `NLog.config`:

```xml
NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(builder => {
   builder.ForLogger().WriteToConsole()
});
```