# How to overwrite nlog.config when using NLogAspNetCoreOptions

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, logging, nlog

This answer shows how to replace or add nlog configuration https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751090/9100849 when using a `LogFactory` however I'm unable to workout how to do this when using `UseNLog()`.

`UseNLog()` can only take in a `NLogAspNetCoreOptions` which only contains `bools`, `strings` and `enums` - nothing to replace or add additional logging rules.

How am I able to add additional nlog attributes when using `UseNLog()`?

Comment: `UseNLog()` provides a simple out-of- the-box-experience, where NLog automatically loads configuration from [NLog.config](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Tutorial) or [appsettings.json](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/wiki/NLog-configuration-with-appsettings.json). Advanced stuff with dynamic adjustment of NLog-configuration can be done using [AddNLogWeb](https://nlog-project.org/documentation/v5.0.0/html/M_NLog_Web_AspNetExtensions_AddNLogWeb_4.htm) or [NLog.LogManager.Setup().LoadConfiguration(builder => ...)](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Fluent-Configuration-API)

Comment: Another alternative is using semi-dynamic-logging-rules, that stays deactivated until activated by configuration-change at runtime. Ex. `minLevel="${gdc:item=DefaultLevel:whenEmpty=Off}"`. See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Filtering-log-messages#semi-dynamic-routing-rules

Comment: @RolfKristensen looking at NLog.LogManager.Setup() how would I use RegisterNLogWeb(configuration, serviceProvider) with this? Where in startup/ program.cs can I access serviceProvider to pass through?

Comment: When using `NLog.LogManager.Setup()` and `RegisterNLogWeb` outside Host-builder, then it is okay to leave serviceProvider unassigned (Also happens with `LoadConfigurationFromAppSettings`). When hooking up NLog-LoggingProvider using AddNLog / UseNLog then it will be wired together.